# Powershell - winrm using ip address instead of computer name

Tags: powershell, winrm

Is it possible to set up winrm using IP address instead of the computer name.

The computer in question is only

I have only been able to set winrm up for a computer in the same domain like this:

```
winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="demox"}
```

The computer I want to connect to is not accessible by computer name.

Answer (score 2):

You can add the IP address to the TrustedHost list:

```
winrm s winrm/config/client '@{TrustedHosts="10.1.2.1"}'
```

Using this I managed to connect to a Windows 2003 server in a different domain, which I could connect to using either, the NETBIOS or FQN name yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add the machine by IP:

[Installation and Configuration for Windows Remote Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384372(VS.85).aspx)